# Expected implicit type conversion not recognised by GNU g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++

The following code results in error: conversion from ‘Local::Int32’ to non-scalar type ‘Interop::Int32’ requested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

typedef int32_t _Int32;

class ByteOrder { };
class LittleEndian : public ByteOrder { };
class BigEndian : public ByteOrder { };

namespace Local {
    class Int32 : public LittleEndian {
        private:
            _Int32  _x;

        public:
            Int32(const _Int32 x = 0) : _x(x) { }
            Int32(const Int32& x) : _x(x) { }
            virtual ~Int32() { }

            operator _Int32() const { return _x; }

            Int32& operator=(const _Int32 x) {
                _x = x;
                return *this;
            }

    };
}

namespace Interop {
    class Int32 : public LittleEndian {
        private:
            _Int32  _x;

        public:
            Int32(const _Int32 x = 0) : _x(x) { }
            Int32(const Int32& x) : _x(x) { }
            virtual ~Int32() { }

            operator _Int32() const { return _x; }

            Int32& operator=(const _Int32 x) {
                _x = x;
                return *this;
            }
    };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Local::Int32 local = 12345;
    Interop::Int32 interop = local;    // *** error: conversion from ‘Local::Int32’ to non-scalar type ‘Interop::Int32’ requested

    std::cout << local << ", " << interop << std::endl;

    exit(0);
}
```

As I understand it the assignment that causes the error (Interop::Int32 interop = local) should accept the implicit conversion provided by the conversion operator defined in Local::Int32::operator _Int32(). Yet the compiler (g++ 5.5) does not seem to be recognising the implicit conversion.

Does anyone know what's going on here or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is no implicit conversion between `Interop::Int32`, to `Local::Int32`. There are only implicit conversion to/from `_Int32`, and converting between those 2 `Int32` classes would require 2 conversions (`Interop::Int32` -> `_Int32` -> `Local::Int32`), yet compiler is allowed to implicitly convert between types that require only one conversion. There should be a duplicate about this topic somewhere..

Comment: `_Int32` is an implementation reserved identifier.

Comment: To elaborate on that, you are not supposed to meddle with reserved identifiers. Fix that first, then retry and either adjust or close your question here.

Comment: Note `<cstdint>` is guaranteed to define `std::int32_t` (if possible), but may or may not also define `::int32_t`.

Comment: I can't find any reference that says _Int32 is reserved. In any case, I changed it to something clearly unique and the result was exactly the same.

Comment: The double conversion problem makes sense. The question is: is there a way to force the conversion implicitly and quietly so I can make this assignment without the need to explicitly cast. For example, Interop::Int32 interop = static_cast<_Int32>(local) works, but this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.